# Add more than 1 of an object to an arraylist

Tags: object, arraylist

So what I'm trying to do is take an object, and add multiples of this same object and put them in an arraylist. I looked around a bit for an answer but could not find one, so I'm hoping someone can help.

Here's an example of what I want:

```
Fish (String name, int weight) {
    -------
    -------
}

bass = new Fish("Bass", 10);

ArrayList<Fish> fishes = new ArrayList<Fish>();

public void method() {

    fishes.add(new bass);

}
```

So all I want in this example code is to add a new object of bass, by calling bass, to the arraylist. I have never done this before so I'm very lost.

Thanks

Comment: You can do `fishes.add(new Fish("Bass", 10));`

Comment: I know but I want to add a new fish like that by only calling bass. Thanks tho.

Comment: Then just do `fishes.add(bass);`, not very sure about your question though. What error message are you seeing when you do the way you want?

Comment: Well, its not an error message, but if I try to add bass to the same list twice (in the case that you have caught 2 of the same fish), each fish needs to have a different weight, but they both share the same weight of the first bass added, if that makes sense. That's why I need to say fishes.add(new bass) or something and not just fishes.add(bass);

Comment: If you do `fishes.add(bass);`, you will have the same object occupying two spots on the list. If you want two objects with same properties, you can do `clone()`, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was easy. I figured this out like a year ago.

```
Fish (String name, int weight) {
    -------
    -------
}

bass = new Fish("Bass", 10);

ArrayList<Fish> fishes = new ArrayList<Fish>();

public void addThisFish(Fish fish) {

    fishes.add(new Fish(fish.name, fish.weight));

}

public void otherMethod() {
    addThisFish(bass);
}
```

That adds a duplicate of the fish using the parameters of the fish you want, so you could add as many bass to the list as you want without conflict.